# Microsoft VS 2015 compiler bug?

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-studio-2015

I have the following function:

```
void MainLayer::onMouseScroll(cocos2d::EventMouse* event)
{
    const float scrollAmount = event->getScrollY();
    const float newMapScale = scrollAmount < 0.f ? std::min(_mapScale * k_deltaMapScaleMag, k_maxMapScale) : std::max(_mapScale * k_deltaMapScaleMin, k_minMapScale);
    const float invNewMapScale = 1.f / newMapScale;

    const Vec2 anchorScreenSpace = event->getLocationInView();
    _mapScale = newMapScale;
    _invMapScale = invNewMapScale;

    updateMapTransform();
}
```

Microsoft VS 2015 compiler generates the following assembly:

```
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push    -1
    push    __ehhandler$?onMouseScroll@MainLayer@@AAEXPAVEventMouse@cocos2d@@@Z
    mov eax, DWORD PTR fs:0
    push    eax
    sub esp, 20                 ; 00000014H
    mov eax, DWORD PTR ___security_cookie
    xor eax, ebp
    mov DWORD PTR __$ArrayPad$[ebp], eax
    push    esi
    push    eax
    lea eax, DWORD PTR __$EHRec$[ebp]
    mov DWORD PTR fs:0, eax
    mov esi, ecx
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _event$[ebp]
; File c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\algorithm

; 3649 :    return (_DEBUG_LT(_Right, _Left) ? _Right : _Left);

    lea edx, DWORD PTR $T1[ebp]
; File e:\projects\aliceandbob\classes\mainlayer.cpp

; 121  :    const float newMapScale = scrollAmount < 0.f ? std::min(_mapScale * k_deltaMapScaleMag, k_maxMapScale) : std::max(_mapScale * k_deltaMapScaleMin, k_minMapScale);

    movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR __real@3f800000
    xorps   xmm0, xmm0
    comiss  xmm0, DWORD PTR [ecx+56]
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [esi+712]
    jbe SHORT $LN3@onMouseScr
    mulss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@3f99999a
; File c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\algorithm

; 3649 :    return (_DEBUG_LT(_Right, _Left) ? _Right : _Left);

    mov eax, OFFSET ?k_maxMapScale@?A0x69cbde3b@@3MB
    comiss  xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@41200000
; File e:\projects\aliceandbob\classes\mainlayer.cpp

; 121  :    const float newMapScale = scrollAmount < 0.f ? std::min(_mapScale * k_deltaMapScaleMag, k_maxMapScale) : std::max(_mapScale * k_deltaMapScaleMin, k_minMapScale);

    jmp SHORT $LN18@onMouseScr
$LN3@onMouseScr:
    mulss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@3f4ccccd
; File c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\algorithm

; 3612 :    return (_DEBUG_LT(_Left, _Right) ? _Right : _Left);

    mov eax, OFFSET ?k_minMapScale@?A0x69cbde3b@@3MB
    comiss  xmm1, xmm0
$LN18@onMouseScr:
    cmovbe  eax, edx
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [eax]
; File e:\projects\aliceandbob\classes\mainlayer.cpp

; 124  :    const Vec2 anchorScreenSpace = event->getLocationInView();

    lea eax, DWORD PTR _anchorScreenSpace$[ebp]
    divss   xmm1, xmm0
    push    eax
    movss   DWORD PTR tv161[ebp], xmm0
    movss   DWORD PTR _invNewMapScale$1$[ebp], xmm1
    call    DWORD PTR __imp_?getLocationInView@EventMouse@cocos2d@@QBE?AVVec2@2@XZ

; 125  :    _mapScale = newMapScale;

    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR tv161[ebp]

; 126  :    _invMapScale = invNewMapScale;
; 127  : 
; 128  :    updateMapTransform();

    mov ecx, esi
    mov DWORD PTR __$EHRec$[ebp+8], 0
    movss   DWORD PTR [esi+712], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR _invNewMapScale$1$[ebp]
    movss   DWORD PTR [esi+716], xmm0
    call    ?updateMapTransform@MainLayer@@AAEXXZ   ; MainLayer::updateMapTransform

; 129  : }

    mov ecx, DWORD PTR __$EHRec$[ebp]
    mov DWORD PTR fs:0, ecx
    pop ecx
    pop esi
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR __$ArrayPad$[ebp]
    xor ecx, ebp
    call    @__security_check_cookie@4
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 4
```

The problem is the compiler generates the code that does not store the result of the expression into newMapScale variable. As you see, it also does not insert minss and maxss instructions here (for std::max() and std::min()). If I deny compuler to use SSE instructions - it works as intended. I tried to reproduce this issue on a test project and failed - almost exact same code had minss and maxss instructions and stored the result of expression into the newMapScale variable. Do I have some kind of undefined behavior, or it's just a compiler bug?

I use VS 2015 Update 3, VS 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp) SDK.

UPD: I only left source code that helps reproducing the problem. Removing any line from that code fixes compiler behavior. Please pay attention to the following lines:

```
    movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR __real@3f800000
    xorps   xmm0, xmm0
    comiss  xmm0, DWORD PTR [ecx+56]
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [esi+712]
    jbe SHORT $LN3@onMouseScr
    mulss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@3f99999a
; File c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\algorithm

; 3649 :    return (_DEBUG_LT(_Right, _Left) ? _Right : _Left);

    mov eax, OFFSET ?k_maxMapScale@?A0x69cbde3b@@3MB
    comiss  xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@41200000
; File e:\projects\aliceandbob\classes\mainlayer.cpp

; 121  :    const float newMapScale = scrollAmount < 0.f ? std::min(_mapScale * k_deltaMapScaleMag, k_maxMapScale) : std::max(_mapScale * k_deltaMapScaleMin, k_minMapScale);

    jmp SHORT $LN18@onMouseScr
$LN3@onMouseScr:
    mulss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@3f4ccccd
; File c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\algorithm

; 3612 :    return (_DEBUG_LT(_Left, _Right) ? _Right : _Left);

    mov eax, OFFSET ?k_minMapScale@?A0x69cbde3b@@3MB
    comiss  xmm1, xmm0
$LN18@onMouseScr:
    cmovbe  eax, edx
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [eax]
; File e:\projects\aliceandbob\classes\mainlayer.cpp

; 124  :    const Vec2 anchorScreenSpace = event->getLocationInView();

    lea eax, DWORD PTR _anchorScreenSpace$[ebp]
    divss   xmm1, xmm0
    push    eax
```

As Andrey Turkin said, xmm0 gets discarded although it contains calculation results. An unitialized memory is loaded into xmm0 instead.

Comment: From a quick glance, it's using branches and cmov instead.

Comment: Yes. it uses branches and cmov, but not in the proper way, ending up with totally different logic

Comment: Get the compiler to produce interleaved source and assembly please

Comment: Well, you only complained it doesn't use `minss` and `maxss`. If you think the generated code is wrong, point out where. Note that it seems to reference `newMapScale` as `tv203[ebp]`.

Comment: Assembly does look wrong. IIRC there was some bug in VS2015 U3 codegen when it used new SSA optimizations. Try disabling that optimizer with `-d2SSAOptimizer-` command line option.  Also please try to minify this sample by removing all unncecessary code (provided bug still manifests of course)

Comment: @AndreyTurkin where exactly is it wrong?

Comment: Here: `cmovbe eax, edx / movss xmm0, DWORD PTR [eax]`. It should've used conditional load from [eax] to xmm0 (to get result of std::min/std::max) and store xmm0 somewhere. Instead if discards xmm0 and does conditional load from either [eax] or [edx] - which at that time points to uninitialized memory.

Comment: @AndreyTurkin I've checked -d2SSAOptimizer- command line option - seems it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on my PC; of course some of stuff I've filled in might've been incorrect and that changed things... Try installing latest version of KB3165756 and see if it changes things. If not then I'd suggest making this minimal code into a complete minimal code (i.e. try to stub all used types/variables/functions so that you have a self-contained piece of code which can be taken and compiled by itself).

Comment: @AndreyTurkin Seems like KB3165756 fully fixed the problem. Now compiler inserts `movss dword ptr [ebp-2Ch],xmm0` between `cmovbe      eax,edx` and `movss xmm0,dword ptr [eax]` Thanks!